# Does file_get_contents() function remember data from file even it is deleted?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Some spooky things happens or at least it seems to me. Namely, I have a simple script that reads text from another file.

```
  $contents = @file_get_contents('/private/filetest01.txt');
  if($contents===false){
  echo "Sorry. There was a problem reading the file.";}
  else{
  echo $contents;
```

Everything seemed ok, until I actually deleted `filetest01.txt` expecting some changes, but the script continued to echo text - why is this? Even the file where text was doesn't exist anymore. So to be clear:

```
$contents = @file_get_contents('/private/filetest01.txt');
```

takes the file from filetest01.txt, and after I had deleted `filetest01.txt`, my script continued to remember data and echoing text. Not just that, but after deleting I made new `filetest01.txt`, with another text, but my script continues to print first, seminal text. I thought it was maybe some browser thing, but, after I pasted address in another browser, the behavior of the script was the same.

What I did next: I deleted file again. My `/private/` folder is empty. I open completely new browser, made completely new script, which function is just to check does deleted file exists.

```
<?php 
if (file_exists('/private/filetest01.txt')){
echo "yes";
}else{echo "no";}
?>
```

It prints "yes". Can someone tell me, what is it all about?

Comment: [Maybe](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) could be the reason that you still see the content

Comment: @Rizier123 :D .. happy 20k

Comment: I don't understand. Maybe?

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks :D Now I joined the 20k club

Comment: welcome! you probably need to explain the joke to OP.. but it looks like you are right

Comment: @wanderer Reload the page with `Ctrl+F5` (This clears the browser cache for that site)

Comment: I think it's caching your data from the file, so it doesn't get the data new(@hek2mgl And you have a [badge more](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer) ;))

Comment: Thank you. But ctrl+f5  doesn't clear anything. It is very strange because, when I copy/paste  address of my script in new browser, it remembers text, although file doesn't exist anymore, and although in that browser script never runs, I mean it was not ran when the missing file exists. That is why I think it is not browser thing at all. The very script bring the information somehow. Or I am crazy. Thanks anyway.

Comment: So, I put whole script in if conditional  regarding deleted file existence, if (file_exsists("/private/filetest01.txt"))- run the script, to check, and it reads deleted file as it exists.

Comment: If that is the case @wanderer then the file does exist. Navigate to it through your finder/file explorer (if this is a local development environment) or through the web server terminal and make sure it really doesn't exist. Are you on a multi-server environment? If so ensure that the file is stored in a central location (ie: a CDN, s3, NFS) and only manage files from that location

Comment: I am on my local server wamp. I only checked via windows computer, and total commander, and it seems deleted. How else  can I check?

Comment: try navigating through your command prompt to the location of the file and verifying that it does not exist. Wish I could be more specific on how to do that but I am not very familiar with windows

Comment: Is your `/private/` folder located at `C:/private/` or somewhere else?

Comment: Remove @ !!!! Never use it! catch the error!

Comment: Hum it's possible to  prevent the error in this case, but catching it: no. wanderer i bet with you your file exists and you are deleting something else in the wrong path or the wrong server...